# Session.Logon() vs Session.Logon(,,True,True)

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm testing out a mailbox connected to exchange, exchange version 2010 outlook version 2010 cached mode on. The exchange is offline in this scenario or there's connection issues.

If I use the following method

```
RDOSession.Logon 'Blank parameters
```

I will get a MAPE_E_FAILONEPROVIDER error when I retreive folders. However, if I use

```
RDOSession.Logon ,,True,True 'Prompt to choose the profile
```

Everything process normally. The behavior that I want is as follows:

If the user select "Always prompt" for a profile to choose, I want the code to prompt. If the user select a default profile, I want the code to run silent and select the default profile. I also want both options to run flawlessly when cached mode is on and there's connectivity issues.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved part of the question by myself. I'm checking this key:

> HKCU\Microsoft\Software\Exchange\Client\Options\PickForProfile

and use different logon method depending if it's true or false. But this does not solve error that I'm having when the user does not pick a profile.

Comment: If you need to show the profile selection dialog, you need to pass the window handle to be used as the dialog parent in the ParentWindowHandle parameter.